# LIKE keyword with PDO execute query wont work

Tags: php, sql, database, pdo, prepared-statement

It's returning false, I've been through couple other answers on this forum tried everything, double quotes, single quotes.. and still giving a hard time. Someone please explain.

Thanks.

```
$query_string = $this->conn->prepare('select category_id, thread_id, thread_title, thread_body from thread where thread_title LIKE :thread_title OR thread_body LIKE :thread_body');
$query_string->execute(array(':thread_title'=>"%$this->search_this%", ':thread_body'=>"%$this->search_this%"));
```

Comment: bind params as strings

Comment: So what value does `->search_this` contain? Does it work with a literal/string-mashup query?

Comment: @mario nothing too interesting really. $this->search_this = $_GET["search_query"]; I swear to god I'd same thing/query hours ago working perfectly...

Comment: Perhaps whitespace in the input or something. Try with static strings for testing. I'm afraid this isn't answerable without the actual DB being available; because the code looks very much ok.

Comment: As embarrassing it is lemme go ahead and say this.. I'd removed db pass and user from from file so i could upload it to github... and forgot re adding info to the file.. "without actual db being available" kind of gave me a clue... thanks @mario

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
$query_string = $this->conn->prepare('select category_id, thread_id, thread_title, thread_body from thread where thread_title LIKE :thread_title OR thread_body LIKE :thread_body');
$query_string->execute(array(':thread_title'=>'%'.$this->search_this.'%', ':thread_body'=>'%'.$this->search_this.'%'));
```

Please let me know, if there is any issue.

Comment: I have not seen any answer like that in your answer list. Try it.

Answer (score -1):

SQL like query is like

SELECT category_id, thread_id, thread_title, thread_body FROM thread
WHERE thread_title LIKE 'Thread Title';

or you can write it like in this way
SELECT category_id, thread_id, thread_title, thread_body FROM thread
WHERE thread_title LIKE 'Thread Title%';

that mean your search string goes in between ''(single quotes)

I am not use the pdo sql code like your way, I write it in this way

$query_string = $this->conn->prepare("select category_id, thread_id, thread_title, thread_body from thread where thread_title LIKE '%".$this->search_this."%' OR thread_body LIKE '%".$this->search_this."%'");
$query_string->execute();

Comment: thats not a very good answer or what im looking for sir. thanks anyways